# plot area width and height in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, height, width

How can I read the width and height of the plot area in a HighCharts chart?
I don't mean the width and height of the whole chart, but only of the plot area, that excludes the x and y axes labels and borders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `chart.plotWidth` and `chart.plotHeight`.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How do you expect to get some help, when you are not describing your issue a little more? Probably you have old version of Highcharts. Also, these variables are read-only.

Comment: chart.plotWidth and chart.plotHeight are undefined.  I'm using a version of Highcharts I downloaded just a few months ago.

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/67/ For me works perfectly.. actual version is 3.0.5